# Vertical menu not working right when opening sub menu

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML layout :

```
<ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="sub">
      Sections  
      <ul>
         <li>Add Section</li>
         <li>Edit Sections</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
```

and CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.main-menu {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.main-menu > li {
    height: 22px;
    width: 170px;
    background: rgb(178,225,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(178,225,255,1) 0%, rgba(102,182,252,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(178,225,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(102,182,252,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(178,225,255,1) 0%,rgba(102,182,252,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(178,225,255,1) 0%,rgba(102,182,252,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(178,225,255,1) 0%,rgba(102,182,252,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(178,225,255,1) 0%,rgba(102,182,252,1) 100%); /* W3C */




filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b2e1ff', endColorstr='#66b6fc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.70);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.70);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.70);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.main-menu li:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.30);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(70, 58, 70, 0.30);
    color: #CC0000;
}
.main-menu li ul {
    display: none;   
}
.main-menu > li.sub:hover ul {
     display: block;   
}
```

I'm using `css-gradient` for `li` elements so it will have fixed `width` and `height`, when I hover on `li` to display sub menu it will work but it doesn't have place under main `li` to fit because of fixed `width`.

I want a solution so I can use `gradient` and display sub menu

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54Q2n/14/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the height of the list items to get larger on hover, just add a `height:auto;` to the `.main-menu li:hover`

[Here is the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/54Q2n/19/)

You'd probably want to change the gradient for the sublist items to make it appear smoother

**EDIT**: [Here is a version with individual gradients](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/54Q2n/20/)

Comment: I know that but you forget the `gradient` because I want to add custom `CSS` for sub menu, I can't put `gradient` at the top for `li` like `background-repeat: no` for images, `gradient` will fill all `li` and there will be no place for sub menu

Comment: Ah, so you want to have a different gradient on just the sub-menu items?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: In other words, I want to split the main `li` from sub menu so each one will have custom `gradient`

Comment: One last clarification: Do you want the main `li` to enclose all of the others? Or have sub-list item not enclosed?

Comment: [Try this update and see how you like it](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/54Q2n/20/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flyout of your sub-menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/54Q2n/22/

I just added some CSS for the sub-menu and sub-menu `li`.

**CSS**

```
.main-menu > li.sub:hover ul {
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: -22px;
}
.sub li {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

and then just duplicated the styling for the sub-menu `li` from the main-menu `li` by removing `>` from you selector.  So  `.main-menu > li` to `.main-menu li`.